# Can I use Visual Studio's Assisted IntelliSense with ReSharper's suggestion system?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, intellisense, code-completion

Recent version of Visual Studio added AI-assisted IntelliSense. See below image the star-marked items.

[image]

Many times this AI-assisted IntelliSense works great. ReShaper's suggestion system is more powerful in general and I always stick to it. My question is can I have Microsoft AI-assisted IntelliSense in ReSharper's suggestion system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is can I have Microsoft AI-assisted IntelliSense in
>   ReSharper's suggestion system?

I am afraid that you cannot get your answer as your expected.

**Assisted IntelliSense** is from  [Visual Studio IntelliCode](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/intellicode/) and is a part of Viusal Studio Intellisnese.

However, Resharper is a **third-party** extension and its Intellisense will inherit, overwrite Visual Studio Intellisense and then uses its own features.

**In fact**, it is not compatible with Visual Studio Intellisense. You can check [this document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Auto-Completing_Code.html). Besides, someone has reproted [a similar issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/730558/intelicode-not-working.html).

**So** in use, you can only use one of them(`Visual Studio Intellisense` and `Resharper Intellisense`), but not use them all at the same time.

**As a suggestion**, if you're using VS2019, try switching between them(`Extensions`-->`Resharper`-->`Options`-->`Environment`-->`Intellisense`-->`General`) which this is the only better solution and thanks for Resharper has retained the option to use `Visual Studio Intellisense`.

[image]

**In addition**, if you still want this feature and use both of them at the same time, you should contact with Resharper's support team and hope that they will give you a satisfactory answer.